# grep question, how to filter several type of patterns?

Tags: grep

I'm console newbie.
As I know, matching multiple patterns like this:

```
aaa|bbb
```

But, | character is pipe on console, so how can I specify those multiple patterns for grep?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can escape the pipe and put the pattern in quotes:

```
grep "aaa\|bbb"
```

or use `-E`:

```
grep -E "aaa|bbb"
```

or

```
grep -E aaa\|bbb
```

Comment: The backslash in the first example is unnecessary; the shell removes it and grep never sees it, but the shell would pass the same info to grep if you omitted the backslash.

Comment: @Jonathan: Not so. Try this with and without the backslash. Only the one with the backslash will succeed. `echo -e 'aaa\nbbb\nccc' | grep "aaa\|bbb"`

Comment: @Jonathan: You're better to read about escaping and quotation rule in ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ's answer.

Comment: Different shells ... and the question is meant to be about grep; oh well.  Stuff that worked one way 20 years ago doesn't seem to work the same now - and I can't tell whether I'm misremembering or whether the shells have quietly changed behind my back.

Answer (score 3):

Put "" between your pattern, like  `egrep "toto|name"`

Answer (score 3):

Or you go

```
grep -ie aaa -ie bbb filename
```

to grep for aaa or bbb in filename, case insensitively.

Answer (score 1):

Lastly, you can put your patterns into a file, and use the -f flag.  So `grep -f patternlist.txt files`.  Where patternlist.txt is simply:

```
aaa
bbb
```

Make sure there are no empty lines, though.

--Christopher Karel

Answer (score 1):

Enclose your pattern in single quotes:

```
grep -E 'aaa|bbb'
```

Should your pattern include an apostrophe, enclose it in double quotes:

```
grep -E "its|it's"
```

If it contains both single and double quotes, enclose it in double quotes and prefix with a backslash the characters <kbd>"</kbd>, <kbd>$</kbd>, <kbd>`</kbd> and <kbd>\</kbd>:

```
grep -E "its|it's|letter \"e\"|pay \$20|\`a'|C:\\\\AUTOEXEC\\.BAT"
```

The final example of `C:\AUTOEXEC.BAT` takes into account that backslash is special both to the shell and to the regular expression syntax of egrep.

PS: The [bash quoting page](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Quoting) is a must-read.

Answer (score 0):

`egrep "aaa|bbb|ccc" <file>`

will find all rows with either aaa OR bbb OR ccc  in the file

`egrep -i "aaa|bbb|ccc" <file>`

will find `aaa` OR `aaA` OR `aAa` OR `Aaa` OR `aAA` OR `AAa` OR `AAA` OR ... and the same for every other string enumerated between the pipe `|` characters.